# Unable to generate coefficient matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, fft, ifft

I have the following piece of code and I am trying to calculate the coefficient matrix, `a_k` to solve the linear system to obtain `h[n]`, the impulse response. I am using the inverse fast Fourier transform.

```
N = 9; % period is chosen to be 16
n = 0:N-1; %vector for x must start at n = 0
for k = 1:9
    y3 = zeros(1,9);
    y3(k+1) = N/2;
    y3(N - k + 1) = N/2;  
end
x3 = ifft(y3);

figure;
subplot(2,2,1);stem(n,real(x3));xlabel('n'); //line 52
ylabel('real(x3)');axis([0 N-1 -1 1]);
subplot(2,2,2);stem(n,imag(x3));xlabel('n');
ylabel('imag(x3)');axis([0 N-1 -1 1]);
subplot(2,2,3);stem(n,real(y3)/N);xlabel('k');
ylabel('real(a_k)');axis([0 N-1 -1 1]);
subplot(2,2,4);stem(n,imag(y3)/N);xlabel('k');
ylabel('imag(a_k)');axis([0 N-1 -1 1]);
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Error using stem (line 43)
X must be same length as Y.

Error in fft_examples (line 52)
subplot(2,2,1);stem(n,real(x3));xlabel('n');
```

I'm not sure where I am erring. I know that the matrix of `k` is from 1 through 9. Hence, I did a `for` loop. The y values are becoming mismatched.

Comment: Can you mark the lines 43 and 52 in your code?

Comment: Matlab will automatically expand a matrix or vector when assigning an otherwise out of bounds value. For example, `t=[1, 2];` `t(3) = 3;` gives `t=[1, 2, 3]`.  The line `y3(k+1) = N/2;` will always assign a tenth value in the last loop for `k=9`

Comment: For line 43, it says line 43 inside the actual `stem` definition. Not in the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
size(real(x3))  % --> 1 10
size(n)         % --> 1 9
```

So they are not the same size. You are increasing the size of y3 in `y3(k+1) = N/2;`

Also, why would you want to create matrix y3 in every iteration: `y3 = zeros(1,9);`

Comment: Hmm, so if my `H(e^{...})`  has the following values for a period of 9, can I just simply have the following? `y3 = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]; x3 = ifft(y3);`

Comment: Is `y3` in frequency domain or space?

Comment: `y3` is frequency domain

Comment: If you are sure `ifft` is what you want to do, you can simply do that: `x3 = ifft(y3);` The syntax and the idea are correct based on your explanation.